# How do I remove the nested box in a highlighted menu item in my Android app?

Tags: android, android-layout

When I click on a menu item in my Android app, I get this nested box inside the highlighted item:

[image]

I have this in my `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
     parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorPrimaryLight</item>
  <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimaryLight</item>
  <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondaryLight</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and this in `colors.xml`

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#F39300</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#FDAE09</color>
<color name="colorStatusBar">#e3f39300</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
<color name="colorError">#d50000</color>
<color name="colorEmergency">#ff8a80</color>
```

and I am using this for the ActionBar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
  app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
  app:title="@string/app_name"
  tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
```

Any ideas on how to remove this box so when I click on the menu item, it is highlighted like a button does?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Took a bit of time but did it myself.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

What I had to change in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
     parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
  <item name="popupTheme">@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
     parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryLighter</item>
  <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
  <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimaryDarker</item>
</style>
```

The Toolbar:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

The key is to use `colorBackground` instead of the `background` property and `colorControlHighlight` is of course the highlight color.

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimaryDarker</item>
```